# How do I use my existing Selenium end-to-end project in the applications Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, maven, selenium, testng

I developed a separate project in my Eclipse environment to run end to end regression automation on a client's web application. I am using maven, and running these tests on a schedule.

They want to run the Selenium tests from their project in VS with Visual Studio Online's continuous integration.

As all of the tests are in a separate project, I don't see how this can be done. It seems like VSO's CI process requires you to point to a POM.xml of the project being built. Can I point to the POM or testNG.xml file of another project (which would be my Selenium project)?

I'm not looking for a full solution, just some pointers in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Also, can Selenium Java code even be run by Visual Studio? Or do I have to rewrite my tests in C#

Comment: I am not sure if Visual Studio supports Java code execution because Visual Studio as an IDE is for meant for .NET. With respect to your query can you please help add a bit more context. Maybe call out the project structure etc., so that it adds a bit more clarity.